# Detect user clicked Facebook login button

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there an event using the facebook API for when a user has clicked the facebook login button but before they have actually authenticated?  Basically, I need the same event that triggers the popup to open.

I'd like to close my modal when facebook opens theirs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your own button, call your own function and use `FB.login`:

```
function onLoginClick() {
    //do your thing

    FB.login(...);
}
```

More information:

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: Ahhhh, my popup blocker was blocking when just calling direct from the console - that explains alot..  Thanks

Comment: yes, of course you can only use FB.login on mouse interaction